# How to detect a tablet device in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

I am trying to port my application developed for smartphones to the tablets with minor modifications. Is there an API in Android to detect if the device is tablet?

I can do it by comparing the screen sizes, but what is the correct approach to detect a tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would introduce "Tablet mode" in application settings which would be enabled by default if resolution (use total pixel threshold) suggests it.

IFAIK Android 3.0 introduces real tablet support, all previous versions are intended for phones and tablets are just bigger phones - got one ;)

Comment: What is Tablet mode?  How does it discern between Kindle Fire and Samsung Galaxy Note?

Answer (score 18):

I don't think there are any specific flags in the API.

Based on the GDD 2011 sample application I will be using these helper methods:

```
public static boolean isHoneycomb() {
    // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in later versions
    // of the OS since they are inlined at compile time. This is guaranteed behavior.
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}

public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}

public static boolean isHoneycombTablet(Context context) {
    return isHoneycomb() && isTablet(context);
}
```

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/UIUtils.java)

Comment: Thanks sam, i will surely give it a try.

Comment: Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE defines a screen with at least 480x640 dp and XLARGE with at least 720x960 dp. The Galaxy Nexus smartphone has a resolution of 1280x720 - and it's not a tablet. Is there any simple way to resolve the screen dimension (e.g 7" or 10.1") in relation to the screen width and height?

Comment: DP is not equal to screen resolution. The Galaxy Nexus's smallest width is 360dp (portrait mode). Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

Thinking on the "new" acepted directories (values-sw600dp for example) i created this method based on the screen' width DP:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the current device is a smartphone or a "tabletphone"
 * like Samsung Galaxy Note or false if not.
 * A Smartphone is "a device with less than TABLET_MIN_DP_WEIGHT" dpi
 * 
 * @return true if the current device is a smartphone or false in other 
 * case
 */
protected static boolean isSmartphone(Activity act){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int dpi = 0;
    if (metrics.widthPixels < metrics.heightPixels){
        dpi = (int) (metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density);
    }
    else{
        dpi = (int) (metrics.heightPixels / metrics.density);
    }

    if (dpi < TABLET_MIN_DP_WEIGHT)         return true;
    else                                    return false;
}



 public static final int TABLET_MIN_DP_WEIGHT = 450;
```

And on this list you can find some of the DP of popular devices and tablet sizes:

Wdp / Hdp

GALAXY Nexus: 360 / 567
XOOM: 1280 / 752
GALAXY NOTE: 400 / 615
NEXUS 7: 961 / 528
GALAXY TAB (>7 && <10): 1280 / 752
GALAXY S3: 360 / 615

Wdp = Width dp
Hdp = Height dp

Comment: as im note sure if this is working or not, i just can recommend to have a better wording for your methods. A Method which is called : isSmartphoneOrTablet with a boolean as return value should only return false on google TV or things like this.

Answer (score 0):

place this method in onResume() and can check.

```
public double tabletSize() {

     double size = 0;
        try {

            // Compute screen size

            DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            float screenWidth  = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;

            float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi;

            size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) +

                                 Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));

        } catch(Throwable t) {

        }

        return size;

    }
```

generally tablets starts after 6 inch size.