# Locking Screen Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I want to lock my screen orientation for Android tabs and for handsets too. I want to lock my phone screen orientation as Portrait and tabs screen orientation as Landscape.

When i searched the solution for the same,then I got the solution as  in manifest file,.But If i will use it,then it work for both the same,but my requirement is to use different orientation for different device..Suggest me something..

Comment: Activity.setRequestedOrientation

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity

Comment: I think that doesnot work for me as that link was to stop the activity to restart again when the user rotate the phone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511330/how-to-detect-a-tablet-device-in-android/7511399#7511399 should help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One each Activity you can take one check to know device type. In my app, I have used screen resolution as check; as tablets are having much more resolution than mobile devices:

```
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int height_pixel = dm.heightPixels;
        int width_pixel = dm.widthPixels;
```

After this you can take resolution bounds to set orientation for mobile and tablets. like

```
 if((height_pixel*width_pixel)>***your_resolution_check***){
      this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}else{
      this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

This works fine for me.