# Android Honeycomb application running on ICS (Ice Cream Sandwitch)

Tags: android, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application developed for Honeycomb (initially 3.0) and after the ICS is released the users can install it to theirs phones with ICS, not just to tablets. How can I filter these phones? I have tried with the `<support-screens>` but that is not working. Also an interesting (at least to me) thing my application won't scale down to smaller screens. I used fixed sized controls but the size is in dp.

In short:

1. Somebody knows how can I filter the ICS phones? (preferably from code)
2. What should I do to support ICS phones? (I guess I need to implement a whole new layout for the ICS phones, but it is still a question to me how can I determine what kind of device is it, phone or tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean isHoneycomb() {
    // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in later versions
    // of the OS since they are inlined at compile time. This is guaranteed behavior.
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}

public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}

public static boolean isHoneycombTablet(Context context) {
    return isHoneycomb() && isTablet(context);
}
```

Copied from this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8427523/253583

You will also probably want to restrict Android Market from enabling users to install this on phones with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks. With a little modification its working how i imagine it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
    //ics
}
```

where Build is android.os.Build class

Comment: Thanks, can't see the forest for the trees :). Btw any idea for the second issue ?

Comment: Anyway this is not good, i can't decide with this if its a phone or tablet. I assume they have the same version number (14).

Comment: The best way to do this is by creating a BaseActivity that asks a "factory" class which behavior to use depending on the result of the condition above. The BaseActivity class will then use an interface to tell the actual Activity what behavior to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your app being shown in the Market for tablets, in your AndroidManifest.xml use the `<support-screens>` attribute (more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)). Make sure you use both indentifiers for before Honeycomb 3.2 (x-large, large) and 3.2+ (600dp etc).

And what exactly do you mean by "my app doesn't scale down"? Could you give more information here?

Comment: I don't know why but when i have tried this on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus the app started without any problem because the phone's screen resolution is HD (or FullHD?) (x-large, bigger then 600dp).  I mean by "my app doesn't scale down" that when i started the app from the screen only a part was visible (the center), i used dip for every user control so theoretically it was good.

Comment: ah okay. That behaviour on your Nexus is actually expected because whilst the amount of standard pixels is greater than 600, the amount of dip isn't. The Galaxy Nexus is an xhdpi device, meaning that 2 standard pixels are equivalent to 1 dip, giving it a shortest width of 360dip. A tablet with the same 1280x720 standard resolution is only mdpi so 1 standard pixel is one standard dip.